# How to prevent Sublime Text 2 from opening iA Writer .md files?

Tags: sublimetext2, osx-mountain-lion

Sublime Text 2 on Mountain Lion always makes itself the preferred app to open `.md` files. I use iA Writer for my programming notes which saves files as `.md`.

Every time when I right-click "Open As…" and select the "Always with this app" option and then select iA Writer from Applications folder, it reverts back to Sublime Text.

Even when Sublime Text is not even running. I found no options to teach Sublime Text or the OS which files to open with which program.

*I need iA writer for my programming notes because of the larger font. It helps me think sharper. So it is programming related. Also when I work in Sublime Text for code I like the clear separation of notes taking and coding.*

Answer (score 1):

In Finder, right-click (or Ctrl-click) on a `.md` file and select the `Get Info` option. In the window that pops up, select iA Writer from the `Open with:` dropdown menu, then click the `Change All` button just below it. Confirm the dialog that pops up, and now all Markdown files should be associated with the correct app. The association may change upon updating Sublime or installing the beta of ST3, but it's easy enough to change back.

The reason your previous action wasn't working was because you were only associating that particular file with iA Writer, not all `.md` files.